# Prove that a function has a unique root

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, roots

I am trying to prove this function has a unique positive root in $\lambda$ for any $\beta>0$ and $\eta>0$ (as background, this is the first derivative of a function I try to prove is unimodal).
Graphically, I cannot find any counterexample. I can prove the function has a root since $f(0)>0$ and $\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow \infty} f\left(\lambda\right)<0$; but would like to go one step further and show that this root is unique. Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks!

$$ f\left(\lambda \mid \beta, \eta \right)= \frac{1}{\beta +\eta-e^{-\frac{\lambda}{\beta }} (\beta +\lambda)
   }-\frac{1}{\eta + e^{-\frac{\lambda}{\beta }} (\beta +\lambda)} -\frac{\lambda^2 e^{-\frac{\lambda}{\beta }} \left(\frac{1}{\left(\eta + e^{-\frac{\lambda}{\beta }} (\beta +\lambda) \right)^2}+\frac{1}{\left(\beta +\eta-e^{-\frac{\lambda}{\beta }} (\beta +\lambda)
   \right)^2}\right)}{\beta }$$

P.S. Strictly speaking, I only need to show uniqueness on $\lambda\in\left[0, -\beta\left(1+W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{2e}\right)\right)\right]$, where $W_{-1}$ is the secondary branch of the Lambert function. But my experimenting with the function seems to suggest the root is unique for any positive $\lambda$.

[image]

Comment: Consider divide the domain into two parts and show that the function is monotonic on each of them.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not. The function can be decreasing again for large $\lambda$. Something I'm trying now is to show that the function is negative at any point for which its first derivative is zero (i.e., there are no positive peaks).

Comment: If you set $z=e^{\tfrac {-\lambda}\beta(\beta+\lambda)}$ and then consider the function $g(\lambda, z)$, is there something you can conclude about the zeroes of that function? Eg, if all the zeroes of it lie on some curve, maybe you can then show that the path that $\lambda$, $z$ takes can only intersect it once?

Comment: Good suggestion, but still led me to a dead end. The roots for $z$ (3 of them) are very un-tractable.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but I think it's close with some additional inequality-chasing on your part.

Denote $a(\lambda, \beta, \eta) = \eta + e^{-\lambda/\beta}(\beta+\lambda)$ and $b(\lambda, \beta, \eta) = \beta + \eta - e^{-\lambda/\beta}(\beta+\lambda)$. Since $a(\cdot), b(\cdot) > 0$ for all $\lambda, \beta, \eta > 0$, $f(\lambda|\beta,\eta)$ has a unique root in $\lambda$ if and only if
\begin{align*}
g(\lambda, \beta, \eta) \overset{\text{def}}{=} a(\lambda, \beta, \eta)b(\lambda, \beta, \eta)f(\lambda|\beta, \eta) = a(\lambda, \beta, \eta) - b(\lambda, \beta, \eta) - \frac{\lambda^2}{\beta}e^{-\lambda/\beta}\left(\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{a}\right)
\end{align*}
has a unique root in $\lambda$. Henceforth, I will sometimes denote functions as $a(\lambda), b(\lambda), g(\lambda)$, or sometimes without arguments as $a, b, g$ if there is no confusion.

First, note that for any $k \in \mathbb{R}$
\begin{align*}
g(k\lambda, k\beta, k\eta) = k g(\lambda, \beta, \eta)
\end{align*}
Showing that $g$ is 1st-order homogeneous. Without loss of generality, we can set $\eta$ to any constant to only deal with two arguments $(\lambda, \beta)$. (In my search, I set $\eta = 1$, but will keep the derivations below as general as possible.)

Secondly, to prove that $g$ has a unique root in $\lambda$, it suffices to prove that for all $\beta > 0$ there exists an $\xi > 0$ such that
\begin{align*}
g'(\lambda, \beta) < 0, \lambda \in (0, \xi) \quad \text{and} \quad g(\lambda, \beta) < 0, \lambda \in [\xi, \infty)
\end{align*}
Since this means $g$ is decreasing until it hits a negative value, and then stays negative henceforth.

With this in mind, note that
\begin{align*}
g(\lambda) = - (\lambda - r_1(\lambda))(\lambda - r_2(\lambda))
\end{align*}
where $r_1, r_2$ are the smaller and larger values, respectively, of
\begin{align*}
\frac{2e^{-\lambda/\beta} \pm \sqrt{4e^{-2\lambda/\beta}-4\frac{e^{-\lambda/\beta}}{\beta}(\frac{a}{b}+ \frac{b}{a})(1-2\exp(-\lambda/\beta))\beta}}{2\frac{e^{-\lambda/\beta}}{\beta}(\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{a})}
\end{align*}
If $r_1, r_2$ were not covarying with $\lambda$, then they could be viewed as roots of the quadratic, in which case $g<0$ always if the discriminant (quantity under the square root) is negative. Using the inequality $\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{a} \ge 2$, one can show that the discriminant is negative whenever $\lambda > \log(\frac{5}{2})\beta \approx 0.916\beta$. Perhaps we wish this could be our value of $\xi$, but it's not strong enough through my attempts, but at least we can now focus on regions $\lambda \le 0.916\beta$.

For $\lambda \le 0.916\beta$, you can show that $\lambda > r_1(\lambda)$ always, so a necessary and sufficient condition for $g(\lambda) < 0$ is for
\begin{align*}
\lambda &> r_2(\lambda) \\
&=\frac{2e^{-\lambda/\beta} \pm \sqrt{4e^{-2\lambda/\beta}-4\frac{e^{-\lambda/\beta}}{\beta}(\frac{a}{b}+ \frac{b}{a})(1-2\exp(-\lambda/\beta))\beta}}{2\frac{e^{-\lambda/\beta}}{\beta}(\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{a})} \\
&= \beta\left(\left(\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{a}\right)^{-1} + \sqrt{\left(\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{a}\right)^{-2} + (2e^{-\lambda/\beta}-1)e^{-\lambda/\beta}\left(\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{a}\right)^{-1}}\right)
\end{align*}
and the derivative of $g$ is
\begin{align*}
g'(\lambda) = 2e^{-\lambda/\beta}\frac{\lambda}{\beta}\left(1 - \frac{\lambda}{\beta}\right) - (\beta + 2\eta)^2 \frac{\lambda}{\beta}e^{-\lambda/\beta}\left(\left(2-\frac{\lambda}{\beta}\right)h(\lambda) - \lambda h'(\lambda)\right)\frac{1}{h^2}
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
h(\lambda) &= \eta(\beta+\eta) + \beta e^{-\lambda/\beta}(\beta+\lambda) - e^{-2\lambda/\beta}(\beta+\lambda)^2 \\
h'(\lambda) &= \frac{\lambda}{\beta}e^{-2\lambda/\beta}\left(2\lambda - \beta\left(e^{\lambda/\beta}-2\right)\right)
\end{align*}
There is a lot of flexibility in finding this function $\xi$; in my simulations, as well as the plot you show, $f$ (and also $g$) becomes negative before it is increasing again, so you just need to find a function $r^*(\beta)$ between those two  two points. One suggestion to find an approximate solutions to $\lambda = r_2(\lambda)$, but solving this takes some time, a bit too much for me. Hope this helps.